# How to print chart for NDWI

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, landsat-7, normalized-difference-water-index

Trying to compute chart for NDWI

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_8DAY_NDWI')
                      .filterDate('1999-01-01', '2002-12-31')
                      .filterBounds(mumbai);
    var colorized = dataset.select('NDWI');
    var colorizedVis = {
      min: 0.0,
      max: 1.0,
      palette: ['0000ff', '00ffff', 'ffff00', 'ff0000', 'ffffff'],
    };
    Map.setCenter(72.88, 19.154, 10);
    Map.addLayer(colorized, colorizedVis, 'Colorized');
    print(ui.Chart.image.series(colorized, mumbai));
```

Error:

```
Error generating chart: Error in map(ID=19990525):
Image.reduceRegion: The default WGS84 projection is invalid for aggregations. Specify a scale or crs & crs_transform.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The imagery in your collection have originally had different projections, because it is built from Landsat scenes of different WRS paths/rows. Subsequently, you will need to provide a scale in the arguments of the `ui.Chart` function to tell GEE specifically how you want to aggregate pixels within the geometry. Use for example a scale of 30 (in meters), which is the nominal scale of Landsat imagery.

```
ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: colorized, 
  region: mumbai, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), // default 
  scale: 30, // nominal scale Landsat imagery 
  xProperty: 'system:time_start' // default
}));
```

[Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0bda32f4e52f9670fbd1f2aa59565937) with random geometry as that was not provided.

Comment: thanx if i increase the scale will it effect the data accuracy?

Comment: Yes it will: [link](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/scale)